# Using Bash For Loop to Search File for Unique Line

Tags: bash, grep, uniq

I have a file `sortedfile.txt` with a list of file names. I am looking to search another file , `ngfilelist.txt` containing a file list for all duplicates files in `sortedfile.txt`.

I am using this command

```
 for X in `uniq -d ~/Desktop/sortedfiles.txt`; do grep "$X" ~/Desktop/ngfilelist.txt; done
```

What should I correct in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
cat sortedfiles.txt | xargs -n1 -i{} grep '^{}$' ngfilelist.txt
```

Instead of using a `for` loop, I find easier to use `xargs` to run a `grep` for every line in `sortedfiles.txt` against `ngfilelist.txt`. The output is a list the file names found in both files.

Note that `^` and `$` are used to match only complete file names since probably partial matches aren't considered as valid results to your problem.

Comment: I believe the `cat` should be `uniq -d` for my problem, but this looks like a solution. I have determined that it is actually Cygwin, not my command, that isn't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{f[$1]++;next}$1 in f && f[$1]>1{print}' sortedfiles.txt ngfilelist.txt
```